# Javascript doesn't work with ujs's new generated DOM element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ujs

Javascript doesn't work with ujs

The following DOM generated by ujs (ajax call).

However the onClick event doesn't work at all with the dynamic-generated DOM ?

It supposed show the alert window when I click on the dropdown options, but it didn't.

How could I fix the issue.

```
  %select
    - @items.each do |item|
      %option{:value => "#{item.code}", :onClick => "alert('hihi');"}= item.introduction
```

Comment: Have you tried with onchange event?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `the dynamic-generated DOM`.

You can't use `onclick` on an `option` tag. 
Use `onchange` event on select tag instead:

```
%select{:onChange => 'if (this.value == "itemcode"){alert("hihi")}'}
  - @items.each do |item|
    %option{:value => item.code}= item.introduction
```